# Which one to is better for cloud service regarding inactive account policy, Google Drive or iCloud Drive?

Tags: google, apple

Does Google (2 years) or Apple (1 year) will keep my account if I have been inactive for more than 2 years even if I keep paying Google Drive or iCloud Drive?

I cannot find it in Terms. As I am a paying customer, simply having the app running in the background (as in the smartphone) without actively interacting with it would be considered my account as active even if I never doing task as follow (from Google terms):

This revealed in Google Terms page:

A Google Account that is in use is considered active. Activity might include these actions you take when you sign in or while you’re signed in to your Google Account:

```
Reading or sending an email
Using Google Drive
Watching a YouTube video
Sharing a photo
Downloading an app
Using Google Search
Using Sign in with Google to sign in to a third-party app or service
```

Google Account activity is demonstrated by account and not by device. You can take actions on any surface where you’re signed in to your Google Account, for example, on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are paying, your account is active.  What you are reading is the blurb for Google Drive's free account.  I am sure Apple will be the same.  I don't think that either will want to stop receiving free money ?